# Is it possible to access chrome devtools modified CSS scripts content?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have a webapp that is aimed at editing a HTML document inside the browser. In order to save some time with not writing a fully fleged CSS editor, I thought I might just use the devtools provided by chrome in order to edit the HTML document. However, after editing the CSS files, I need to write the changes to my backend in order to save them.

Is there a way to access the (modified) contents of the devtools css editor using some kind of chrome javascript APIs? I also wouldn't mind to write an extension for chrome.

Comment: Have a similar need. Any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this html web editor [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/)